# hi I'm new to ROS I'm tying to write a simple c++ program please help me with this error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:53:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/saighi/sai/src/beginner_tutorials/script/talker.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/format/free_funcs.hpp:22:38: note:   ‘boost::str’
     std::basic_string<Ch, Tr, Alloc> str(const basic_format<Ch, Tr, Alloc>& f) {
                                      ^
/usr/include/boost/format/free_funcs.hpp:22:38: note:   ‘boost::str’
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/script/talker.cpp.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

this is my
CMakeList

```
----------


----------


----------


----------
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Add support for C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_definitions(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/beginner_tutorials.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/beginner_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_beginner_tutorials.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker script/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

----------
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257449/hi-i%27m-new-to-ros-i%27m-tying-to-write-a-simple-c++-program-please-help-me-with-this-error/) by [lolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29759/lolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-03-20**:
We can't really help you if you don't post the source code. Only the error message and the CMakeLists.txt does not provide enough information

**Comment by [Bogdar_](https://answers.ros.org/users/25988/bogdar_/) on 2017-03-22**:
More information about your source code is needed (+1). Follow the ROS writting a simple publisher tutorial again. Be sure that you have include in your code all needed headers and that you create the executable in  CMakelists as it is explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you really haven't uncommented important blocks in your file.

1. Uncomment `CATKIN_DEPENDS`
2. Uncomment `add_executables`and `target_link_libraries`(If you want your source code to be converted to executables)

Check if these changes resolve the problem

---

Originally posted by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) with karma: 231 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0